# Select combobox if wrong item selected

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an MS-Word 2013 document with several (legacy) formfields; some text boxes, some comboboxes. The first list item on all of the comboboxes is "(select one)" to let the end user know they need to make a selection (I did not draft or design this document, I've just been asked to write the VBA code for it). So I coded each to give a simple VBA message box, ran on exit, if that first selection was not changed, for example:

```
Public factor1 As Integer
Sub MyFormFieldFactor1()
  If ActiveDocument.FormFields("cbofactor1").Result = "(select one)" Then
    MsgBox "You must select either Yes or No."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If ActiveDocument.FormFields("cbofactor1").Result = "Yes" Then
    factor1 = 1
  Else
    factor1 = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

The word document automatically goes to the next formfield when you click ok on the message box. Through VBA, I want it to stay on the current formfield when "(select one)" is chosen. Bonus points if it stays on the current field and pulls up the list selection automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("cbofactor1").Result = "(select one)" Then
    MsgBox "You must select either Yes or No."
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("cbofactor1").SetFocus()
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You can auto drop the list with something like:

```
 SendKeys "%{down}", True
 DoEvents
```

Full code:

```
If ActiveDocument.FormFields("cbofactor1").Result = "(select one)" Then
    MsgBox "You must select either Yes or No."
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("cbofactor1").SetFocus()
     SendKeys "%{down}", True
     DoEvents
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: It seems that SetFocus is not a supported property in MS-Word for FormFields... but I *may* be able to use SendKeys and tab backwards... hold that thought!

Comment: SendKeys "+{TAB}", true may work for that purpose. Seems cryptic, but as long as it works! :-)